# AutoFixture AutoMoq not use my mocks for properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, autofixture

I have an abstract class that I want to test. There is an abstract property in this class for my DAO, which I define in inherited classes.

```
public abstract class DeviceGroupManagerBase<TDeviceGroup> where TDeviceGroup : DeviceGroup 
{
    protected abstract IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup> DeviceGroupDao { get; }

    public TDeviceGroup UpdateDeviceIndexes(Device device)
    {
        return DeviceGroupDao.GetDeviceGroup(device.Group.Id);
    }
}
```

I want to test the Updatedeviceindexes method so I'm trying to mock a property called `DeviceGroupDao`.

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("Unit")]
public class DeviceGroupManagerBaseTests
{
    private IFixture fixture;
    private Mock<DeviceGroupManagerBase<DeviceGroup>> subject;
    private Mock<IDeviceGroupDao<DeviceGroup>> deviceGroupDaoMock;
    private DeviceGroupManagerBase<DeviceGroup> Manager => subject.Object;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        deviceGroupDaoMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDeviceGroupDao<DeviceGroup>>>();
        subject = fixture.Freeze<Mock<DeviceGroupManagerBase<DeviceGroup>>>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestUpdateDeviceIndexes()
    {
        var device = fixture.Create<Device>();
        var deviceGroup = fixture.Create<DeviceGroup>();

        deviceGroupDaoMock.Setup(x => x.GetDeviceGroup(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(deviceGroup);

        var result = Manager.UpdateDeviceIndexes(device);
        // The resultDeviceGroup will not be contain a previously defined object

        Assert.AreEqual(deviceGroup.Id, result.Id);
    }
}
```

I also tried to add registration for my device object in this way:

```
fixture.Register(() => deviceGroup);
```

But I'm still getting a new object.

How can I mock `IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DeviceGroupManagerBase` is an abstract base class, you'll need a [SUT Double](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/06/15/sut-double). It's easiest to do if you make the `DeviceGroupDao` property `public`:

```
public abstract class DeviceGroupManagerBase<TDeviceGroup> where TDeviceGroup : DeviceGroup
{
    public abstract IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup> DeviceGroupDao { get; }

    public TDeviceGroup UpdateDeviceIndexes(Device device)
    {
        return DeviceGroupDao.GetDeviceGroup(device.Group.Id);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use Moq's API for defining and overriding `protected` members, which is possible, but more work.

Then you'll need to override `subject`'s `DeviceGroupDao` property:

```
subject.SetupGet(x => x.DeviceGroupDao).Returns(deviceGroupDaoMock.Object);
```

Here's the full test:

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("Unit")]
public class DeviceGroupManagerBaseTests
{
    private IFixture fixture;
    private Mock<DeviceGroupManagerBase<DeviceGroup>> subject;
    private Mock<IDeviceGroupDao<DeviceGroup>> deviceGroupDaoMock;
    private DeviceGroupManagerBase<DeviceGroup> Manager => subject.Object;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        deviceGroupDaoMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDeviceGroupDao<DeviceGroup>>>();
        subject = fixture.Freeze<Mock<DeviceGroupManagerBase<DeviceGroup>>>();
        subject.SetupGet(x => x.DeviceGroupDao).Returns(deviceGroupDaoMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestUpdateDeviceIndexes()
    {
        var device = fixture.Create<Device>();
        var deviceGroup = fixture.Create<DeviceGroup>();

        deviceGroupDaoMock.Setup(x => x.GetDeviceGroup(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(deviceGroup);

        var result = Manager.UpdateDeviceIndexes(device);

        Assert.AreEqual(deviceGroup.Id, result.Id);
    }
}
```

This now passes on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `DeviceGroupDao` is protected you will need to find a way to access it externally. Create a stub that would allow you set it value.

```
public class DeviceGroupManagerBaseStub<TDeviceGroup> 
    : DeviceGroupManagerBase<TDeviceGroup> where TDeviceGroup : DeviceGroup {

    private IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup> deviceGroupDao;

    public DeviceGroupManagerBaseStub(IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup> deviceGroupDao) {
        this.deviceGroupDao = deviceGroupDao;
    }

    protected override IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup> DeviceGroupDao {
        get {
            return deviceGroupDao;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then mock `IDeviceGroupDao<TDeviceGroup>` and inject it into the stub for your test.

Comment: This answer is useful if the design is completely locked down. It nicely resolves the issue of the property being `protected`, while keeping tests type-safe. It also, I think, demonstrates that Constructor Injection would be a better design overall, so making itself redundant is another benefit of this :)